# Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 for cert-manager ClusterIssuer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

When I try configuring TLS Let's Encrypt certificates for my cluster application with a NGINX Ingress controller and [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/), something goes wrong with the ClusterIssuer.

My ClusterIssuer is defined as followed:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: user@example.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

When I check out the clusterissuer via kubectl, it says that the ClusterIssuer is `READY`.

```
$ kubectl get clusterissuer --namespace mynamespace
```

Response:

```
NAME               READY   AGE
letsencrypt-prod   True    13s
```

But when I describe the ClusterIssuer I get an error.

```
$ kubectl describe clusterissuer letsencrypt-prod --namespace mynamespace
```

Response:

```
Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=ClusterIssuer failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

I installed cert-manager with [Helm 3](https://helm.sh/) with manually adding the CRDs.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cert-manager chart does not accept different namespacing when the CRDs are applied manually to your cluster. Instead of applying them manually first, [install](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) the CRDs as part of the Helm 3 release.

```
$ helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

$ helm repo update

$ helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace mynamespace \
  --version v0.15.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding `namespace: cert-manager` under `metadata`

It would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: user@example.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
   solvers:
   - http01:
       ingress:
         class: nginx
```